# Get a Json file from a specific folder and serialize it

Tags: c#, json

I need to get json file from a specific folder in my solution. the name of the json file is "plaza.json" and the folder it is in is Data. Please see image below.

[image]

How do I get this file and serialize it? I have searched for some answers but the closest is this:

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("plaza.json"))
{
    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
}
```

if I use that, it doesn't see my json file

Comment: Put in the correct path, or add that file as content in right click -> properties. Also `File.ReadAllText` can save you having to use a `StreamReader`. Also if this is a webservice you will probably need to use `Server.MapPath()` to get the correct location, also if this is IIS you might need to add the right permission for your apppool on the file

Comment: This is just a WPF Sir.. Can you give me a sample on the correct path you're saying?

Comment: First start with adding the right build action (content) for the file https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/build-actions?view=vs-2019 that way it will end up in your output directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Data/plaza.json"))
{
    string json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass>(json);
}
```

This should work, haven’t test but check this how file will be accessed
Depending on you project type it can be server.mappath or hostingenvironment.mappath

If desktop app like win forms or wpf use this

```
Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"Data/plaza.json");
```

Make sure to put copy file if modified property in build property

Comment: This is a WPF sir now web based. I get an error on the "Server" of the "Server.MapPath..."

Comment: @Ibanez1408 updated answer check, you may need to adjust the path a bit, I haven’t tested it

Comment: It's almost there It gets to the folder but this is where it gets to => "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'D:\Projects\Lane\Antenna_Reading\TagReporting\TagReporting\bin\Debug\TagReporting.exe\Data\plaza.json'.' but the file is in: "D:\Projects\Lane\Antenna_Reading\TagReporting\TagReporting\bin\Debug\Data"

Comment: It shouldn't include the "TagReporting.exe". After "Debug", it should go to "Data\plaza.json".

Comment: @Ibanez1408 already told you to adjust the path, use Path.GetDirectoryName

Comment: Thank you. This is how I did it => "var streamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(), "Data/plaza.json"))"

Comment: @Ibanez1408 this works without any checks Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,"Data/plaza.json");